# How to block gmail / google modal by clicking on the image inserted in the body PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Using the `AddEmbeddedImage` functionality of `PHPMailer` I can add images in the design of the mail template, such as logo and other images that decorate the design of the mail template.

```
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('email-info.png', 'emailimg', 'attachment', 'base64', 'image/png');
```

And use it:

```
$mail->Body = '<img src="cid:emailimg" class="mail" />';
```

Or

```
$mail->Body = '<img src="https://example.com/img/email-info.png" class="img-logo" />';
```

The image is correctly added to the template design.
The problem is that if the receiver or reader clicks on some of the images, it opens in a modal as if it were an attachment when it is not.

Some configurations that should be considered or added to `PHPMailer` to prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 0):

There is literally nothing that PHPMailer can do about this. It’s entirely dependent on the behaviour of email client apps such as gmail. As far as the RFCs go, there is no significant difference between images that are embedded or attached. Linked images are just like those in any web page.

In short, no, you can’t change this behaviour.